# How to rename /page.php?1 to /welcome.html in htacces?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rename, file-rename

I have a cms that does not generate friendly url's

What is the best way to rename this without getting double content by google.

Now I have in .htacces:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule welcome.html page.php?1[L]
    RewriteRule about-us.html page.php?2[L]
```

Is this the best way to do?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has no problem spidering and indexing this very simple dynamic URL scheme. But if you want extra onpage-optimization-bonus-points with the help of keyword-stuffed-URLs it would be best you switch to a CMS that creates them automatically. You save time by avoiding to maintain the link-scheme manually both in your content and the rule-file.

If not there's always the chance you forget to replace those dynamic links with your readable ones if you create new content. Also your cms will always answer both variants: the friendly one and the dynamic one, so you have to tell Google the "canonical" URL ([Explanation here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)) to avoid duplicate content. This might happen because you can't tell how people link to content on your site.